# Defining episodes in longitudinal data

Tags: r, longitudinal

I have a dataset, in which I would like to define 'episodes'. An episode is defined if there is an increase or decrease of temperature for at least 15 minutes. 
Is there any way to structure this without doing it manually?

This is the structure of my data:

```
Patient  Minute temperature
1 0,00  35,65
1 1,00  35,65
1 2,00  35,66
1 3,00  35,67
1 4,00  35,70
1 5,00  35,72
1 6,00  35,71
1 7,00  35,68
1 8,00  35,66
1 9,00  35,67
1 10,00 35,69
1 11,00 35,72
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` possibility to achieve it could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(episode = temperature > lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(episode = (n() >= 4) * episode) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid) %>%
 left_join(df %>%
            mutate(episode = temperature < lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
            group_by(rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
            mutate(episode = (n() >= 4) * episode) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            select(-rleid), by = c("Patient" = "Patient",
                                   "Minute" = "Minute",
                                   "temperature" = "temperature")) %>%
 mutate(episode = pmax(episode.x, episode.y)) %>%
 select(-episode.x, -episode.y)

   Patient Minute temperature episode
     <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <int>
 1       1      0        35.6       0
 2       1      1        35.6       0
 3       1      2        35.7       1
 4       1      3        35.7       1
 5       1      4        35.7       1
 6       1      5        35.7       1
 7       1      6        35.7       0
 8       1      7        35.7       0
 9       1      8        35.7       0
10       1      9        35.7       0
11       1     10        35.7       0
12       1     11        35.7       0
```

Please notice that I decreased the number of days from 15 to 4 (you can change it by modifying the number in `n() >= 4`) as your data does not contain enough rows for illustration on that many days.

And what it does is, it, first, compares whether a row has a higher/lower (it does it separately for the two conditions) "temperature" value than the previous row. Second, it creates a run-length type group ID around this comparison. Third, if the condition is fulfilled for `n` rows (in my code it is 4), it assigns 1 in a variable called "episode". Finally, it combines the results of the comparisons from the first step.

Or if you want to also distinguish the episodes:

```
df %>%
 mutate(episode = temperature > lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(episode = (n() >= 2) * episode) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid) %>%
 left_join(df %>%
            mutate(episode = temperature < lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
            group_by(rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
            mutate(episode = ((n() >= 2) * episode + 1) * episode) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            select(-rleid), by = c("Patient" = "Patient",
                                   "Minute" = "Minute",
                                   "temperature" = "temperature")) %>%
 mutate(episode = pmax(episode.x, episode.y)) %>%
 select(-episode.x, -episode.y)

   Patient Minute temperature episode
     <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1      0        35.6       0
 2       1      1        35.6       0
 3       1      2        35.7       1
 4       1      3        35.7       1
 5       1      4        35.7       1
 6       1      5        35.7       1
 7       1      6        35.7       2
 8       1      7        35.7       2
 9       1      8        35.7       2
10       1      9        35.7       1
11       1     10        35.7       1
12       1     11        35.7       1
```

Here, using 2 windows, "episode" == 1 means an increase, "episode" == 2 a decrease.

And I suppose that you would like to group by "Patient", so you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Patient) %>%
 mutate(episode = temperature > lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
 group_by(Patient, rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(episode = (n() >= 2) * episode) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid) %>%
 left_join(df %>%
            group_by(Patient) %>%
            mutate(episode = temperature < lag(temperature, default = first(temperature))) %>%
            group_by(Patient, rleid = with(rle(episode), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
            mutate(episode = ((n() >= 2) * episode + 1) * episode) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            select(-rleid), by = c("Patient" = "Patient",
                                   "Minute" = "Minute",
                                   "temperature" = "temperature")) %>%
 mutate(episode = pmax(episode.x, episode.y)) %>%
 select(-episode.x, -episode.y)
```

Comment: If you consider the post helpful, please accept it :)